# Salesforce Opportunity update using api

Tags: salesforce

Please help me, I'm using SalesForce Enterprise API for update Opportunity  with my C# code:

```
QueryResult query = service.query("SELECT ID,ChargentSFA__Gateway__c FROM Opportunity WHERE       AccountId = '" + accountItem.Id + "'");
if (query.records != null && query.records.Length > 0)
{
Opportunity opportunity = query.records[0] as Opportunity;
SaveResult update_result = new SaveResult();
opportunity.Acct_Email__c = accountItem.PersonEmail;
update_result = service.update(new sObject[] { opportunity })[0];
if (update_result.success)
{
// TODO
}
else
{
Logs(update_result.errors[0].message);
// TODO
}
}
```

All data input is true but it away show me a error with

> StatusCode.FIELD_FILTER_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION
>
> Message: "Please choose an Active Gateway record"
>
> Error field: ChargentSFA_*Gateway*_c

Please give me your opinion on this error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chargent CC Gateway object the opportunity is referring to has been deactivated. And the error message is from a validation rule preventing references to inactive gateways.

For more information see the documentation [here](http://www.rogueit.net/support/chargent.php#gateway)